# why cstdio undef gets or other functions

Tags: c++, c

When I read [libstdc++-v3/include/c/cstdio](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c/cstdio),I'm quite confused about the lines below:

```
//Get rid of those macros defined in <stdio.h> in lieu of real functions.
#undef getc
#undef gets
```

I think that `getc` is a macro but `gets` is a function in fact, why undef a function?
May be in some system it's all implemented in macro?

---

**Update:**
I try to put my understanding about `<stdio.h>` and `<cstdio> here`

```
<stdio.h>=
__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
extern int fgetc (FILE *__stream);
extern int getc (FILE *__stream);
__END_NAMESPACE_STD
#define getc(_fp) _IO_getc (_fp)

<cstdio>=
#undef getc
```

- Macro may have some side effect which leads us not to use,but I can't
  putforward such an occasion for getc(_fp) above.
- For safety,Maybe we can involke `fgetc` rather `getc` or undef the macro `getc` manually.
- `getc` is a weak alias for `IO_getc` ,when macro `getc` is not taken
  into effect,the alias for function will work(eg,in C++ implicitly ).

Answer (score 1):

The comment clearly implies that in `<stdio.h>`, both `getc` and `gets` <s>are</s> could be (function-like) macros. The C standard certainly allows this. The C++ <s>compiler</s> library code, for whatever reason, does not want the macros exposed to the C++ program; it wants to ensure that functions are invoked.

Comment: When i read the glibc,I find that `gets` is a weak alias for `__IO_gets` function. why you say that they are both macros?

Comment: Because the comment says it is making sure that any macros for `getc` and `gets` are undefined.  And because `#undef getc` ensures that if `getc` was defined as a macro, it is not defined as a macro afterwards; similarly for `gets`.  I said nothing about weak aliases or other such declarations.